# Cleaning up noise from answers

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

I was reading the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42247/are-semicolons-needed-after-an-object-literal-assignment-in-javascript) today and found a few of them to be rather full of noisy ego battles.  There may however be a couple bits of useful information amidst the combat.  It's a popular enough question that I think it should be cleaned up but feeling a bit unsure about editing out something which the community finds valuable, since I tend to assumed someone else would have done so by now.

On the other hand, I find the back and forths there inappropriate.  Can I get some advice please regarding edits this specific question and scenarios like this going forward?

Comment: Wow, those answers are a bit of a mess.  Removing the sniping and just leaving the responses below relevant quotes with attribution would make them more clear and less noisy.

Comment: The site explicitly disallows using answers to address the user who posted the question; I don't see any reason why addressing other users who posted answers should be treated any differently. Deleting the text addressing specific users from the answers would be appropriate.

Comment: Well, do pay attention to the date. These posts were from back in 2008, before the comment feature was introduced. So it's not like these people are just stupid, egotistical maniacs. They were doing what you were *supposed* to do back then, editing your responses to others into your post.

Comment: @CodyGray I wouldn't say what they were 'supposed' to do; as the idea was not to have discussions (hence why it's a Q&A); but they did it because they wanted to have cross talk. Hence why comments were introduced.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've taken a pass at editing the answers to take out the cross talk and make sure it was included in the answer itself (if anywhere).  You're right, that question and its answers were a mess.

In the future feel free to suggest edits or to get on a chatroom and ask for advice on how to edit; but since you have edit privileges you should feel free to edit that stuff out.

Comment: thanks for making those edits.  seeing what you did gives me better picture of how to address stuff like this in the future.